# [move_base] want to completely follow the global path

Tags: navigation, move-base, base-local-planner

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Dear all,
I am using move_base for my robot navigation, 
and following the [tuning tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/navigation/Tutorials/Navigation%20Tuning%20Guide) to adjust my yaml file which used in base_local_planner.
ex: 
pdist_scale:1.0
gdist_scale:0.5
But my local plan path is doesn't not follow the global path completely.
[image: image description]
Is there any advice for tunning these parameter?
EX: rotate to direction first.
[Demo video of completely follow the global path](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j8OYlSZcqMc)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/241474/%5Bmove_base%5D-want-to-completely-follow-the-global-path/) by [Jam](https://answers.ros.org/users/27716/jam/) on ROS Answers with karma: 77 on 2016-08-10

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

One possible answer: the scales are NOT [0,1]. Try cranking pdist_scale up to 11.

---

Originally posted by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) with karma: 10932 on 2016-08-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Jam](https://answers.ros.org/users/27716/jam/) on 2016-08-10**:
Thank you, David!  
Set pdist_scale up to 11 works! 
The robot will rotate first, then almost follow the path!
Thanks for your kindly help again :)